# Fscrawler logs in Kubernetes and logstash

Tags: kubernetes, logstash, fscrawler

I have a Kubernetes Fscrawler deployment with several instances. The logs are mapped to a Persistent Volume.

I have also Elasticstack 8 with Logstash.
What I would like to do is sending the logs from the different Fscrawler to logstash to have a sort of global logging for Fscrawler Instances.